# People found dead in Whiterun

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After few quests, I returned to Whiterun to see dead guards stripped.

I searched their bodies, and they still had their helmet, armor, shoe, etc but they were naked... also in Dragon's Reach, some female servants were dead too... so I went into my house to see Lydia dead.

I used console to resurrect every dead person I saw, only to see them dead again after I return from another adventure...

Anyone else having this issue?
Possible fix?

Comment: Sounds like a case of the rattles! ... it's very contagious

Comment: Have you ruled out [this possibility](http://www.facepunch.com/threads/631191)?

Comment: I actually found my first companion dead and naked in my house, on the second floor. This was my Whiterun house, so I believe it has something to do with the town or part of the whole "take over cities for this faction" deal you have to do. My advice, drag the bodies to a more discrete part of town.. or showcase them.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I think Whiterun has some sort of death glitch since I once walked into my house there and walked back out about 5 in game min to suddenly be facing 3 dead guards and the body of a dead dragon. Since it wouldnt be possible for tem to kill a dragon in 5 in game min im assuming it was a death glitch which is affecting you in a different way.

Comment: the respawning dead dragons is apparently a well-known bug; the dead guards is a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same glitch, except some of the corpses were burnt. It has to be a glitch.

The second possibility is bandit raids, which are a random event where bandits come in, kill people, steal stuff, and strip people of their armour. It can be pretty brutal (I found Lydia dead, stripped of armour and a sword through her abdomen).